# How to remove line "freeshipping $0.00" under shipping method in magento

Tags: magento, checkout

I don't want to remove module "shipping method" because we inserted "contact form" in shipping method in checkout.

How to remove line "freeshipping $0.00" under shipping method in magento.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [magento.se]

Answer (score 1):

Go to Admin > System > Configuration > Shipping Methods .
Search Free Shipping tab and disable it.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your reply.
I wanted that freeshipping tab. But I want to delete the line freeshipping $0.00 . Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean, you want to change text or remove completely. Can you explain clearly what you want or asked on magento stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I wanted to delete the text "freeshipping only", i don't want to remove shipping method.

Comment: You can leave blank in method name and set text as you like. But it will still remain $0.00. But what is the use case for doing like that?

Comment: Hi,

Thanks a lot for reply. 

I left the method name, blank. Unfortunately It did't worked for me. 

as we are using freeshipping, I don't want to see " freeshipping $ 0.0

in shipping method. because buyers again have to select the "freeshipping $ 0.0"

dropdown box to go to "payment option" method.

SO i wanted to remove that line.